# SQL difference Calculation from two table or views

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-express, except

I have a supervisor table and No. of Working Days=5.I also have a absent tabale.Now I to calculate Present Days from two table.How to get this.

```
 SupList    WorkDays
    101         5
    102         5
    103         5
    104         5
    105         5
 Suplist   AbsentDays
    101         2
    103         1
```

Now I want to get this

```
Suplist      PresentDays
101         3
102         5
103         4
104         5
105         5
```

Comment: Please show your attempt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select s.Suplist , (s.workDays - isnull(a.absentDays,0)) as PresentDays
from supervisertable s
left join absentTable a
on s.suplist=a.suplist
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7192/2)

Answer (score 0):

**Refer Following Query:**

```
select p.Suplist,(p.WorkDays-a.AbsentDays) as PresentDays 
from presentTable p,absentTable a 
where p.Suplist=a.Suplist
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a outer join so that if a person is not absent then also you can provide the present days count for him.

```
Select s.Suplist , (s.workDays - nvl(a.absentDays,0)) as PresentDays
from supervisortable s
left outer join absentTable a
on s.suplist=a.suplist
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select 
    a.SupList, 
    a.WorkDays-isnull(b.AbsentDays,0) PresentDays
from 
    Supervisor a LEFT JOIN Absent b on a.SupList=b.Suplist
```